# AAPT: error: attribute android:clipToOutline not found

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, aapt

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugResources
>   Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > Android resource linking failed
  >   C:\Users\user\StudioProjects\IMPwala\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main2.xml:23: AAPT: error: attribute android:clipToOutline not found.

  C:\Users\user\StudioProjects\IMPwala\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main2.xml:87: AAPT: error: attribute layout_constrainttop_toTopOf (aka com.example.impwala:layout_constrainttop_toTopOf) not found.

  C:\Users\user\StudioProjects\IMPwala\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main2.xml:87: AAPT: error: attribute android:clipToOutline not found.

  C:\Users\user\StudioProjects\IMPwala\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main2.xml:150: AAPT: error: attribute android:clipToOutline not found.

  C:\Users\user\StudioProjects\IMPwala\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main2.xml:212: AAPT: error: attribute android:clipToOutline not found.

  C:\Users\user\StudioProjects\IMPwala\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main2.xml:274: AAPT: error: attribute android:clipToOutline not found.

  error: failed linking file resources.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 54s
12 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 10 up-to-date

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Due to a bug the `android:clipToOutline` attribute is not recognised and will throw a compiler error when trying to build. I've read that using `android:outlineProvider="background"` is working in some cases, but for me it doesn't work. A workaround is to programmatically set `view.setClipToOutline(true)` in Java or `view.clipToOutline = true` in Kotlin on your view.